# Iphone Help Overview of document like in ibooks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface

Hey guys just wondering if anybody could help me,
I have a simple magazine app where the images are loaded from an array into a image view.
On the ibooks app there is a button which will take you to a type of overview with all the pages deconstructed as buttons where you choose the page. They are like 3 pages accross and then down. Is this just a table view or somethin different im confused?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A table view can only have one column, so probably not that.

Without seeing it, they could have just placed an array of `UIImageView` or `UIButton` objects on screen or maybe if you want a longer list you can place them into a `UIScrollView`

Comment: Hey how would you put the array into a imageview just to list them as an index say?

Comment: if it's a table of contents or an index in one single column, that's probably a table view.